# Вывести самый маленький элемент в массиве в виде матрицы + его индекс

Tags: массивы, c++

Например : массив (40,30,10,50,20) - самый маленький элемент - 10 его индекс в массиве 2  , как это записать с помощь циклов ? Заранее спасибо.

```
include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    const size_t rowsCount(4);
    const size_t colsCount(5);

    int matrix[rowsCount][colsCount];
    std::cout << "Input the matrix: " << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < colsCount; j++) {
            std::cout << "matrix[" << (i + 1) << "][" << (j + 1) << "]: ";
            std::cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    std::system("cls");

    std::cout << "Matrix: " << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
        int minimal(*matrix[i]);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < colsCount; j++) {
            std::cout << std::setw(5) << matrix[i][j];
            minimal = minimal > matrix[i][j] ? matrix[i][j] : minimal;
        }
        std::cout << "\tMinimal: " << minimal << std::endl;
    }

    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Facktor, уточните, вам нужен один минимальный элемент из всей матрицы или построчно, как это сделано сейчас? Если один, то см. ответ @BuilderC.

По поводу индекса(ов). А что мешает запомнить индекс(ы) одновременно с тем, как записываете значение минимального элемента в 'minimal'?

Answer (score 2):

Вам, вообще-то, не нужны последние два цикла, т.к. минимум можно найти в процессе ввода данных (первые 2 цикла). А если уж так необходимо, то инициализацию минимума нужно делать до циклов, а вывод после них.